# SCRIPT Expect - Waiting for the end of an exec

Tags: linux, bash, wait, expect

I have an expect script that has to launch a ssh session and expect the result of it.

When it raises a RSA key error, it has to call a bash script which have to erase one line of a file and call the script back to test the ssh connection again.

But, this script is also launched from a bash script a certain number of times. (the number of IP in a file)

*> bash ssh_bash.sh ipfile.txt cmdfile.txt user pwd*

Here is my code:

**[ssh_bash.sh]**

```
#!/bin/bash

row=$(cat $1 | wc -l)
modulus=$(($row%$4))
declare -A tab
declare -A tabthread

for rows in $(cat $1);do
   tab[$compt]=$rows
   compt=`expr $compt + 1`
done

tabthread[0]="LOGG/_ssh-1-"`date +%Y%m%d%H%M`".temp"
compt=0
for k in `seq 0 $(($modulus-1))`;do
   ./ssh_bash.expect ${tab[$compt]} $2 ${tabthread[0]} $3 $4 &
   compt=`expr $compt + 1`
   wait
done
fi

#sleep 5

touch $log
for logfiles in "${tabthread[@]}";do
   cat $logfiles >> $log
   rm -f $logfiles
   compt=`expr $compt + 1`
done

echo "Process finished!"
```

**[ssh_bash.expect]**

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

set ip [lindex $argv 0];
set cmdfile [lindex $argv 1];
set log [lindex $argv 2];
set _user [lindex $argv 3];
set _pwd [lindex $argv 4];
set _timeout 0
set _issue 0

log_file $log
log_user 0

spawn ssh -o ConnectTimeout=5 $_user@$ip

expect {
  "assword"                          { send "$_pwd\r"                                                                         }
  "yes/no"                           { send "yes\r"
                                       exp_continue                                                                           }
  "port 22: Connection timed out"    { set _timeout 1                                                                         }
  "verification failed"              { exec bash rsa_eraser.sh ${ip} ${cmdfile} ${log} ${_user} ${_pwd} &
                                       wait
                                       set _issue 1                                                                           }
       }

if {$_timeout == 0 && $_issue == 0} {
   send "$cmd\r"
   expect {
         "OK"       { puts "$ip | $cmd : OK"    }
         "ERROR"    { puts "$ip | $cmd : ERROR"
                      set _error 1              }
        }
}
```

**[rsa_eraser.sh]**

```
#!/bin/bash

cp -f /root/.ssh/known_hosts /root/.ssh/known_hosts.back
ligne=`grep -n $1 "/root/.ssh/known_hosts" | cut -d: -f1`
sed -i "$ligne d" "/root/.ssh/known_hosts"
echo "Erasing existing RSA...done!"
./ssh_bash.expect $1 $2 $3 $4 $5
```

For example there is only one IP on the ipfile.
So,

```
for k in `seq 0 $(($modulus-1))`;do
   ./ssh_bash.expect ${tab[$compt]} $2 ${tabthread[0]} $3 $4 &
   compt=`expr $compt + 1`
   wait
done
```

Loops only one time.
But if the RSA error raises, the script doesn't wait the end of the :

```
./ssh_bash.expect $1 $2 $3 $4 $5
```

of the rsa_eraser.sh script.

The only way I found to solve this issue is to put a "sleep 5" just before logging in the "ssh_bash.sh" script.
Thanks!

Comment: What's an "RSA error"? Show us what that looks like.

Comment: This error is prompt when the RSA key corresponding to your IP isn't equal to the one which is in the /root/.ssh/known_hosts file.

It looks like : http://www.witheringtree.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/rsa.png

(sorry for the link but the output was too long to be post on a comment)

Comment: That's should be an exception. Do you want to handle that automatically, or do you want to figure out why the remote server's fingerprint has changed?